# What does this output and how?

Tags: java, string

I'm learning Java and I have no idea what this outputs, if someone could explain how this works and what it outputs. Thank you in advance.

```
    Label displayLabel = new Label();
    String str1 = "As dead as a doornail";
    String str2 = str1.substring(3, 9);
    displayLabel.setText(str2 + str1.substring(str2.length()));
```

Comment: Look at docs of that method

Comment: It's a good thing we have we have compilers and application launchers.

Comment: In which package the Label class is?

Answer (score 0):

Label is a class object.
Substring is used to snip parts of the String
the first substring,
    str1.substring(3, 9);
goes by the string class which haves 2 parameters, substring(int begin, int end) which will give you the letters starting at begin till it reaches the desired ending letter.

that substring will give you "dead as" because the first letter will begin with 0.

> str1[0] = 'A'
>
> str1[1] = 's'
>
> str1[2] = ' '
>
> str1[3] = 'd'
>
> str1[4] = 'e'
>
> str1[5] = 'a'
>
> str1[6] = 'd'
>
> str1[7] = ' '
>
> str1[8] = 'a'
>
> str1[9] = 's'
>
> str1[10] = ' '
>
> str1[11] = 'a'
>
> str1[12] = ' '
>
> str1[13] = 'd'
>
> str1[14] = 'o'
>
> str1[15] = 'o'
>
> str1[16] = 'r'
>
> str1[17] = 'n'
>
> str1[18] = 'a'
>
> str1[19] = 'i'
>
> str1[20] = 'l'

so following each letter, starting with 0, you must begin the string @ 3, which is d, till it ends @ 9, which is at d. that's how you get "dead as".

now the other substring.. which is different from the first one

```
str1.substring(str2.length())
```

this one only haves 1 parameter, and the meaning of this is whatever number that is in this is when we will start snipping.
so... str2.length() is the number the user chooses, which in this case is 7.. dead = 4, space counts as 1, and as = 2.
We will start counting from str[7], which is a space. We will take everything from that space till the end.

which gives us " as a doornail"

Now... this entire code..

```
str2 + str1.substring(str2.length())
```

means we will combine str2, which was "dead as" and the previous substring we just did " as a doornail"

and it will give us... "dead as as a doornail"

```
displayLabel.setText
```

this method, that is from the Label class, will now set the text that will be labeled as "dead as as a doornail".

That's all to it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code doesn't output anything. You are creating a `Label` object. It doesn't create any visual or text outputs. It only adds some new objects to memory. Let's look at it line by line.

```
Label displayLabel = new Label();
```

This line creates a new `Label` object called `displayLabel`.

```
String str1 = "As dead as a doornail";
```

This line creates a string object, which has the value "As dead as a doornail" and is called `str1`.

```
String str2 = str1.substring(3, 9);
```

This line creates another string. It's value is a substring of `str1`. In the method arguments, we know that it is the letter at index 3 to the letter at index 9 of `str1`. aka "dead as".

```
displayLabel.setText(str2 + str1.substring(str2.length()));
```

As you can see here, this line sets the text of the display label you created in the first line. So what text exactly? `str2` + `str1`'s substring.

str1.substring(str2.length()) evaluates to " as a doornail". And then plus `str2`, the value is "dead as as a doornail".

**Summary: the code creates a label with the text "dead as as a doornail"**

Answer (score -1):

The first line creates and initializes a Label object. The second line creates a new String the value of which is "As dead as a doornail". Very straitforward so far.

The third line takes characters from the first string starting from the *fourth* character (at index 3) to the 9th character which in this case are "dead a".

The fourth line evaluates the String that is inside the setText() method and sets that as the text on the label. The evaluation goes like this:

first we take str2 the value of which like stated previously is "dead a" and at the end of the value of str2 we append the value of str1.substring(str2.length()) which is "d as a doornail". 
So combining "dead a" with "d as a doornail" we get "dead ad as a doornail" which we be the text on your label.